# How can I use same color picker to change background and text color also?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I am trying to do is when the user clicks on the background of the div then the color picker would change the background and if clicked on its text then the same color picker will change text color.

```js
 var box1 = document.querySelectorAll('.color1');
var picker = document.getElementById('colorpicker');
setInterval(() => {
       let color = picker.value;
          for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          box1[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
             }
                }, 200);
```

```css
div{
  height: 200px;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<input id = "colorpicker" type = "color" value = "#ffffff">
 <div class = "color1" contenteditable = 'true'> color changes </div>
<div class= "color1"id = "c" contenteditable = 'true'> how are you </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another variable, that works as a toggle. Example textIsClicked.
if textIsClicked is true then change the text color, if textIsClicked is false then change the div color.

I hope it helps, but i think its the best if u have 2 color picker for each element. :)